# MYSQL QUERY to join multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for single query where I can connect multiple tables. 
The Query is as follows
 `

```
SELECT
a.name as module_name,
a.id,
b.id as subject_id,
b.SUBJECT_name,
c.id as course_id,
c.course_name,
d.id as cordinator_id,
d.cordinator_name
FROM module_table a
LEFT JOIN subject_table b ON b.id = a.subject_id
LEFT JOIN course_table c ON c.id = a.course_id
LEFT JOIN cordinator_table d ON d.id = a.cordinator_ids
WHERE a.id = $somevalue
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

`

Above query is producing error and when I am connecting the two tables Its showing all right

```
SELECT
a.name as module_name,
a.id,
b.id as subject_id,
b.SUBJECT_name
FROM module_table a
LEFT JOIN subject_table b ON b.id = a.subject_id
WHERE a.id = $somevalue
ORDER BY a.id DESC`
```

The first Table has all foreign keys for subject and course table, further subject table is connected to coordinator table with common id column..  I want the corresponding names of the id given in the module table..

The last table is the result of query I want from where I can collect my required data
My table structures are below

MODULE CAN BE INCLUDED ONLY IN A SUBJECT AND SUBJECT CAN BE INCLUDED IN COURSE
EACH SUBJECT CAN HAVE ANY NUMBER OF CORDINATORS WHICH I AM KEEPING THEM AS JSON  value

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
MODULE TABLE
_____________________________________________________
id   |   subject_id  |   course_id |  cordinator_id |  name


-----------------------------------------------------------------------
COURSE TABLE
__________________
id  |  course_name

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SUBJECT TABLE
_________________________________________________
id    | course_id  |  cordinator_id |  SUBJECT_name


-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CORDINATOR TABLE
______________________________________
id  |  cordinator_ids |  cordinator_name


Result TABLE
___________________________________________________________________________________________
id  | module_name | subject_id | subject_name |  course_id  | course_name  | cordinator_ids
```

I am able to join two tables successfully with LEFT Join but on third it is reporting an error.

Comment: what is the error ? what tables you want to connect ? what is your query ?

Comment: yeah, i've got an error too.

Comment: Then you're obviously doing it wrong, since there's no reason you shouldn't be able to join as many tables as you want. I can't give a more specific answer if you don't show your SQL.

Comment: SELECT a.name as module_name, a.id, b.id as subject_id, b.subject_name, c.id as course_id, c.course_name, d.id as cordinator_id, d.cordinator_name FROM `module_table` a
LEFT JOIN `subject_table` b ON b.id = a.subjectid_id
LEFT JOIN `cordinator_table` d ON d.id = a.cordinator_id
WHERE a.id = $somevalue
ORDER BY a.id DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a few typos and forgot to JOIN course_table.

Here is the right query:

```
SELECT
a.name as module_name,
a.id,
b.id as subject_id,
b.SUBJECT_name,
c.id as course_id,
c.course_name,
d.id as cordinator_id,
d.cordinator_name

FROM module_table a
LEFT JOIN subject_table b ON b.id = a.subject_id
LEFT JOIN course_table c ON c.id = a.course_id
LEFT JOIN cordinator_table d ON d.id = a.cordinator_id
WHERE a.id = $somevalue
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

On this line:

```
b.SUBJECT_name,
```

you had to put uppercase "SUBJECT_name" as in your table subject_table schema.

And your query was lacking this JOIN to allow you to select course_table fields:

```
LEFT JOIN course_table c ON c.id = a.course_id
```

Comment: The first four tables are the given table ... and last one is required values ..

The first table has all connected id to different table, I want to connect those id to get their respectiVe names
QUERY I am tryiing : 
SELECT a.name as module_name, a.id, b.id as subject_id, b.subject_name, c.id as course_id, c.course_name, d.id as cordinator_id, d.cordinator_name FROM `module_table` a
LEFT JOIN `subject_table` b ON b.id = a.subjectid_id
LEFT JOIN `cordinator_table` d ON d.id = a.cordinator_id
WHERE a.id = $somevalue
ORDER BY a.id DESC

Comment: Until you have the comment privilege, please do not post your comments as answers

Comment: @user689: Instead of running on the features of stack please either reply proper answer or follow other ques

Comment: @atjoshi when you downvote an answer it is more recommended to tell why you did, in that way also I can know if the poster edited his question so he can notify me and I will remove the downvote. Also how can I answer such a question?

Comment: Samir - Casing only matters for identifiers if they were escaped/delimited at creation time.  Given we don't have the creation scripts, it's impossible to tell if that's an _actual_ problem.